# Rendering error messages in react-redux from form

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, redux, activerecord, react-redux

I'm building a single page Rails application using react-redux to submit Pokemon (with names, items, moves) and display their attributes. I'm working on rendering error messages when a user submits a Pokemon and gets rejected. In the form, I have a submission that redirects the user:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.createNewPokemon(state).then(newPokemon => {
        navigate(`pokemon/${Object.keys(newPokemon.pokemon)[0]}`)
    });
}
```

That `createNewPokemon` function comes from my actions:

```
export const createNewPokemon = (pokemon) => (dispatch) => (
    APIUtil.createPokemon(pokemon).then(
        (payload) => {(dispatch(receiveOnePokemon(payload)))
            return payload
        }, (err) => {dispatch(receivePokemonErrors(err))}
    )
)
```

Which uses my API call to submit

```
export const createPokemon = (pokemon) => {
    return (
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/api/pokemon',
            data: { pokemon }
        })
    )
}
```

I have an error reducer that's supposed to populate the state with errors

```
import { RECEIVE_POKEMON_ERRORS } from "../actions/pokemon_actions";

const errorsReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case RECEIVE_POKEMON_ERRORS:
            return Object.assign({}, action)
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default errorsReducer;
```

from my errors action

```
export const receivePokemonErrors = errors => ({
    type: RECEIVE_POKEMON_ERRORS,
    errors
})
```

When I submit the form with an error, however, my errors slice of state is a huge object with a bunch of functions

[image: errors state slice]

and I can't seem to extract the error message from it to display to the user. Can someone help me figure out what's going on and how to display the error message (which show on my backend console as "`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Name can't be blank`"). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that because I had the controller using the bang methods (`create!` instead of `create`), it would raise an **ActiveRecord::Record-Invalid** exception and not move down to the else statement.